# Is there a way to track the path of a point in a scene of multiple points with p5.js

Tags: javascript, animation, p5.js

I have a scene where a couple of points `P0` to `P4` are moving around the canvas independently of each other for five seconds. When I press a button they all start moving and after five seconds they all stop and if I press the button a second time they start moving again. I need only `P0` to leave a trail when I press the button the first time and the second time it should remove the last trail and replace it with the points new path.

I can't make this work. The only way I know to make the point leave a trail is by removing the background color from the begging of `function draw` but that makes everything leave a trail.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to keep track of the path by storing the coordinates and then drawing the whole trail. This snippet should illustrate the gist of it (click on the canvas to reset the trail drawing):

```js
// Keep track of the path
let trail = []

function setup(){
  createCanvas(400, 180)
  noStroke()
}

function draw(){
  background(50)
  
  // Point with no trail
  fill('red')
  ellipse(mouseX-20, mouseY-20, 10)
  
  // Point with trail
  fill('blue')
  trail.push({x: mouseX, y: mouseY}) // Add latest position to the array
  for(let point of trail)
    ellipse(point.x, point.y, 10) // Draw a circle for each of the positions
  
  // Point with no trail
  fill('yellow')
  ellipse(mouseX+20, mouseY+20, 10)
}

function mouseClicked(){
  // reset the array so a new trail can be drawn
  trail = []
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.0.0/p5.min.js"></script>
```